# app installations overwriting each other

Tags: android, eclipse

I have developed two android apps...when i install them on my phone to test them.. they overwrite each other. I do not want this to happen. The intent is to have both installed on the phone as separate apps.. how do i fix this? I developed them with eclipse.

Answer (score 9):

I had the same problem despite the fact that package names were different between both APKs.

At the end I had to modify a GRADLE file:

> \app\build.gradle

the following line:

***applicationId "name.to.change"***

In Android Studio 3 you will find this configuration in:

[image]

Comment: If you are using Firebase in your app then you also need to replace google-services.json with a new one generated in firebase console with new app id

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue, turned out that I had copied one project to another to save time, and the package setting in the Manifest tag inside the AndroidManifest.xml file was the same for both apps.

Once I changed this and resolved any imports errors, the apps stopped overwriting one another on the phone.

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="xxx.yyy"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >
```

Comment: I did it, and does not work. Each APK has different package and it still overwriting each other. :-(

Answer (score 0):

Do the apps share the same namespace? Verify that they have their own packages in Eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

also share the same user id, modify it in the manifest.